# Model inference problem for multi-class classification

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a CNN model for multivariate classification task. With training, validation and testing accuracy (all reached to around 88% overall), there's not overfitted, and the accuracy for every class is above 80%. However, when I only input data based on one of classes, the model gives exactly different results (wrong label). Say I labelled soybean '2', and the pre-trained model finally considered **all** '2' as '5' which is another class: building area. When I input all classes, from '1'to'6', the classification accuracy for each class was above 80% as before.

I am really confused. All pre-processing steps of data for either input of all class or single class are same. In this case, I cannot make prediction for the whole map from the model since it led to huge misclassified pixels.

Comment: What is the ratio of each class data in your dataset while training the model? Because this could be the reason why the learned model is not able to identify only one class data. Also let us know the dataset size and the model definition to understand the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @TFer2. This issue was solved, which was caused by scaler. e.g., The model was firstly trained with data that was scaled based on 6 classes. Then when I only feed input data that belong to one of classes into the pre-trained model, I didn't apply the same scaler based on all classes, which leads to numeric error corresponding to input data with one label, and further wrong labels were accordingly predicted.

Comment: Good to know that your issue has been resolved and thanks for posting the reason and solution here which may help others. Happy Coding!